# Increase frequency of input capture of stm32

Tags: timer, stm32

I'm going to measure the frequency of an input 6MHz signal. I wrote a code that works with the "input capture" ability of STM32 and it works perfectly for signals with frequencies below 770 kHz. After 770 kHz it can't measure the frequency and it reports a number of about 100Hz surprisingly!!!
I'm using the Discovery board with STM32F407VGT6. Its bus works with 84MHz and 6MHz is not very high to measure! Why did this problem happen?

And I also must mention that when I omit all codes and disable all peripherals of the board, and I write a code to just toggle a pin in while(1), its frequency equals below 5MHz. Is it normal?

I want to measure 6MHz and a little more signal frequency!

You can see my main code. As you can see, I use the "input capture" peripheral of the microcontroller.

```
while (1)
  {
    // compute and print the input signal's frquency, whenever 2 captures occur 
    if(captureState == SecondCapture)
    {
      Ticks = (T2 + (TIM2_overFlowCnt * 65536)) - T1;
        if(i == 1000){
          sprintf(data, "%lu\n\r", Sum / 8);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data, 45, 10);
          i = 0;
          Sum = 0;
        }
        else{
          if(Ticks < 12800 && Ticks > 9600){ //Filtering Correct Data
            Sum += Ticks;
            i++;
          }
        }
      captureState = AwaitingCapture;
    }
```

And here is my ISR's callbacks:

```
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
  
  
    if(captureState == AwaitingCapture)
    {
        TIM2_overFlowCnt = 0;
        T1 = TIM2->CCR1;
        captureState = FirstCapture;
    }
    else if(captureState == FirstCapture)
    {
        T2 = TIM2->CCR1;
        captureState = SecondCapture;
        __HAL_TIM_SetCounter(&htim2, 0);
    }
}
 
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
    TIM2_overFlowCnt++;
}
```

Comment: Your question does not give any information about how you try to measure the input signal. Without that, its nearly impossible to help.
You can share the part of the code, where you gather the inputs and calculate the frequency, if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about it. Sorry.